# Why is overriding trait methods in Laravel AuthController not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to override some of the RegistersUsers trait to suit my needs for an application I'm developing with Laravel 5.2. I want to override the getRegister() method so it can behave differently as its default behaviour.
This is just the basic override I am trying to do:

```
public function getRegister(){
    //Custom behaviour
}
```

I saw that there where some other people having the same issue but unfortunately there was no answer for this.

[Overriding Traits in AuthController](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/overriding-traits-in-authcontroller)

Do you have any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, its PHP. Methods defined on a class override trait methods.

`Route::auth()` which you can use to define auth routes for you, does not register any route that goes to `getRegister` by the way.

> "An inherited member from a base class is overridden by a member inserted by a Trait. The precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods. " - php.net

[PHP - Traits - Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

`Route::auth()` - registration routes.

```
$this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally missed that on the routes:list. You're completely right, that method is not called in any route. I was confused about the getRegister() method because of some info I found on other threads. Thanks for this info.

Comment: no prob, hopefully the `getRegister` and `postRegister` will be gone in the next version. A lot of people get caught by those  :-)

Comment: If you think this solved your current issue, if you can mark this as the accepted answer it might help out some other people as they may have fallen into the same thing. Sorry for my manners - Welcome to SO, may you find all your answers ;)

Comment: Yeah, hopefully they will. As I told you, I've seen other threads about those methods.

Comment: Oh sure! I am new to this as a user, I've always used SO for consulting and learn but never as a logged in user. Thanks, I hope I will! :)